# styled-components, polished and themes

Tags: themes, styled-components, template-literals

I am trying Styled-components in a simple React project, I have a theme object that is passed to the component so I can do:

`background-color: ${props => props.theme.primary};`

I am also using Polished to modify the passed values, so a button uses a darker version of the color as an outline. I can do this with:

`border: 1px solid ${darken(0.05, '#00823b')};`

But I need the color value to be from the theme, how do I go about passing the theme properties in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your `border` style definition like this:

```
border: 1px solid ${props => darken(0.05, props.theme.primary)};
```

[**Working Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/x9l4w8pjrq)