# Styled Components - passing object as second argument for colour function from polished

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

I am using `polished` which [documentation](https://polished.js.org/docs/#tint) can be read about and here [github](https://github.com/styled-components/polished) repo here.

> When writing styles in JavaScript, many people need Sass-style helper functions to be productive. ✨ polished brings them to you in a nice, lightweight package tailor-made for styles in JavaScript.

I am using the `tint` function, an example of how it is used can be found in the documentation link above:

> Tints a color by mixing it with white. tint can produce hue shifts, where as lighten manipulates the luminance channel and therefore doesn't produce hue shifts.

I have a theme object which stores all my colors, it is something like this:

```
const object = {
  colors: {
    myDesiredColor: '#0000FF',
    ...otherColors
  },
};
```

I am then exporting a some styles which I intent to reuse. Like below:

```
export const containerStyles= css`
  color: ${tint(0.5, object.colors.myDesiredColor)};
  padding: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
`;
```

**But I am receiving the following error:**

> Uncaught Error: An error occurred. See https://github.com/styled-components/polished/blob/master/src/error/errors.md#5 for more information.

Unfortunately the above is returning a `404 Error` so I can not see what it says.

I came across this stackoverflow post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812117/styled-components-polished-and-themes) which does work but it's not quite what I'm looking for, as I also use this approach elsewhere, and would not be appropriate for use in those situations. So Ideally I just want to pass in a variable after extracting theme object color.

```
const getMyColor = ({ object }) => object.colors.myDesiredColor;

export const containerStyles= css`
  color: ${tint(0.5, getMyColor)};
  padding: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
`;
```

The above is ideally what I'd want. So that I can easily call it in other use cases. But I get the same error.

I know (believe) it has something to do with how i'm passing in the second argument. I know it expects a string, and I'm assuming that it is not receiving a string, but I don't know how to fix.

I have came across this post, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003397/with-styled-components-and-polish-how-to-include-a-function-as-the-color), but again not sure if this is what I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think in the second code snippet you meant to write `object.colors.myDesiredColor` isntead of `object.color.myDesiredColor`. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when writing this question, I will edit post now but I still get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super late to the party on this, but your issue is `getMyColor` is a function and `tint` is expecting a string as you've stated. We don't evaluate functions passed to any of the color modules, so you must evaluate `getMyColor` when you pass it in. So something like this:

```
const getMyColor = ( object ) => object.colors.myDesiredColor;

export const containerStyles= css`
  color: ${tint(0.5, getMyColor(myTheme)};
  padding: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
`
```

[A working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/2zqq3yvjzr)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your function (getMyColor()) and see the response, if it is not a string, there is your fix.